# Why a $4\times 4$ double degenerate Hamiltonian can be obtained with Clifford algebra matrices?

Tags: condensed-matter, dirac-matrices, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry

in the book - *Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors, B. Andrei Bernevig and Taylor L. Hughes, Princeton University Press (2013), pag 148* - the authors say that **in order to have a $4\times 4$ double degenerate Hamiltonian we need to use the Clifford algebra matrices**:

> [...] so the minimal Hamiltonian that would be able to describe a gap-closing transition at a TR-invariant point is $4\times 4$, with doubly degenerate energies. Hence, need to use the Clifford algebra matrices—these are the only ones that give two sets of bands, each doubly degenerate:
> $$H\left(\vec{k} = \frac{\vec{G}}{2}\right)=E_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{5}d_i\, \Gamma_i$$
> Note that the $d_i$ are constants—they do not depend on k because we have fixed the $k$-point to
> be TR invariant. The $\Gamma$ matrices have to be TR invariant and hence can be chosen as
> $$\Gamma_1 = 1\otimes \tau_x \quad \Gamma_2= \sigma_z \otimes \tau_y \quad \Gamma_3= 1\otimes \tau_z \quad \Gamma_4= \sigma_y \otimes \tau_y \quad \Gamma_5 =\sigma_x \otimes \tau_y$$
> where $\sigma$, $\tau$ operate in spin and orbital space explicitly. Note that, regardless of the representation chosen, there are only five such matrices that are TR invariant.

Here $\vec{G}/2$ is the time reversal invariant point.

My question is:   **Why a 4x4 double degenerate Hamiltonian can be obtained in this way?**